# fixed menu that is fixed after scrolling past a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a fixed position sub-nav menu bar for a responsive site. All the examples I can find of a fixed menu that sticks to top after scrolling are based on a set number of pixels from top.

However, since I am working a responsive site the pixels from top where I need the menu to come in are different based on viewport (on small screens, the menu should appear after more area scrolled down because the content fills are taller area of screen).

I have a working example and am using the following jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#navigation a, #fixedbar a').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});

$(window).on('scroll',function() {
var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();

if(scrolltop >= 215) {
  $('#fixedbar').fadeIn(250);
}

else if(scrolltop <= 210) {
  $('#fixedbar').fadeOut(250);
}
});
});
```

As you can see the fixed bar fades in if more than 215 pixels scrolled from the top. Instead I'd like to have it appear after scrolling past a certain div. That way I know it will come in after user has fully scrolled past the intro text.

[Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHhQE/)

Any good examples out there of what I want to do? Or easy way to modify the jquery script? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This modification will make it fade in after it passes the static nav

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/65JGz/)

```
var $nav = $("#navigation");
if(scrolltop >= $nav.offset().top + $nav.height()) {
  $('#fixedbar').fadeIn(250);
}
else {
  $('#fixedbar').fadeOut(250);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/EHhQE/1/

You need to fade out and fade in the navigation when the scroll reaches the bottom and the top of the navigation bar respectively.

```
var topOfDiv = $('#navigation').position().top;
var bottomOfDiv = $('#navigation').position().top+$('#navigation').outerHeight(true);
```

And fetched in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#navigation a, #fixedbar a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var topOfDiv = $('#navigation').position().top;
    var bottomOfDiv = $('#navigation').position().top+$('#navigation').outerHeight(true);

    if(scrolltop >= bottomOfDiv) {
      $('#fixedbar').fadeIn(250);
    }

    else if(scrolltop <= topOfDiv) {
      $('#fixedbar').fadeOut(250);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    slider();
});

$(window).scroll(function ()
{
    slider();
});

function slider()
{
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 208)
        $('#fixedMenu').fadeIn(0);
    else
        $('#fixedMenu').fadeOut(0);
}
```